# Microsoft ToDo pinning to start menu. 3 tiles wide? Windows10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, microsoft, to-do

I've started using Microsoft To Do to keep my annual work goals pinned to the start menu. However, I've got 4 goals and each tile is either 1, 2 or or 4 tiles wide. Each line is 6 tiles wide, which means I cannot fit them nicely to fill the space.

Is there a way to set a pinned tile to be 3, or even 6, tiles wide? As it stands, I've got each tile to be 2x2, which means I can either have 3 tiles on one line and one below, or 2 tiles per line, but leave an empty column. This is messing with my needs to tidiness as it's leaving empty space.

Comment: Have you done any research on whether/how to force specific sizes on these pinned "widgets" in Windows?

Comment: From what I can tell, app devs get to device on the tile size options. While there are tools to create custom tiles, these don't appear to support live content. It may be possible to open an app package and modify the tile options, but I'd guess at next app update any changes may be overwritten.